# Anti-CSRF tokens in HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, csrf

I'm trying to implement anti-CSRF tokens in this html form, which is submitted via POST and Javascript to the PHP API, but when searching for vulnerabilities it remains as I wouldn't have tried anything.

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(24));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<form name="entry" id="entryForm">
    <label for="EntryName" class="form-label">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" id="EntryName" name="name">
...
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']?>">
    <button type="submit" id="sendButton" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir</button>
</form>
```

The API looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$token = $_REQUEST['token'];
if ($token==$_SESSION['token']){
    $nombre = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $fecha_nacimiento = $_REQUEST['dob'];
    $signosolar = $_REQUEST['signosolar'];
    $signolunar = $_REQUEST['signolunar'];
    $retrogrado = $_REQUEST['retrogrado'];
...

}else{
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 405 Method Not Allowed');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the system and does it work to accept/reject requests with/without the correct token?

Comment: `searching for vulnerabilities`...by what method exactly? And what exact report are you getting?

Comment: I vae tested the system with correct requests and it works. I'm using ZAP for looking for the vulnerabilities and says: "Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens"

Comment: Maybe it checks for some field with a specific name, or something like that. Hopefully this tool has some documentation where you can see exactly what it searches for, or perhaps there is someone you can ask about how to make it compliant. We cannot usually advise about 3rd-party tools on Stackoverflow unless they are publicly documented. If you can link us to any documentation, that could also be helpful (but to be clear, it's not our job to read it all on your behalf - we'd expect a link directly to a relevant area, unless somone else here already knows where to look)

Comment: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/alerts/10202/ refers to https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/blob/main/addOns/pscanrules/src/main/java/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/pscanrules/CsrfCountermeasuresScanRule.java for the code this test uses, and in there you can see that it scans for _"known" anti-CSRF tokens_, the names of which are determined on line #106, `List<String> tokenNames = extAntiCSRF.getAntiCsrfTokenNames();`